# ProjectTo() Entity framework Core

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm following a tutotial ([Link](http://gunnarpeipman.com/2017/01/ef-core-paging/)) to handle paging in a Core 1.1 Web API.

There is a function :

```
public static PagedResult<U> GetPaged<T, U>(this IQueryable<T> query,
                                        int page, int pageSize) where U: class
{
   var result = new PagedResult<U>();
   result.CurrentPage = page;
   result.PageSize = pageSize;
   result.RowCount = query.Count();

   var pageCount = (double)result.RowCount / pageSize;
   result.PageCount = (int)Math.Ceiling(pageCount);

   var skip = (page - 1) * pageSize;
   result.Results = query.Skip(skip)
                      .Take(pageSize)
                      .ProjectTo<U>()
                      .ToList();

   return result;
}
```

I'm using Entity FrameWork Core, and I don't find any `ProjectTo()` function.

Is there an equivalent ? Thanks

Comment: `ProjectTo` is an automapper method, do you reference it? But I dunno if the projection was ported to EF Core yet

Comment: Oh ok thanks, so is there a way to avoir this automapper? Because en EF core it already automap table fields with objects properties because I used the same names.

Comment: AutoMapper doesn't have anything to do with EF Core. It maps any entity to another, based on conventions. Usually used to convert domain/persistence models to dto/viewmodels (but **NOT** other way around, as that causes issues). The projections just will make it so that the binding happens during the query, so not all fields have to be returned from the DB only the ones you need

Comment: But you can replace the `ProjectTo` method with a normal `Select(db => new MyModel { Property = db.Property })`, but this obviously doesn't work with yoru generic method as you don't know the exact model. It is possible, but its not non-trivial task. You'd need to use reflection and Expression threes to generate a `Select` expression which maps to the model you pass in

Answer (score 0):

For those using Automapper 8.0 or above, this is now:

```
_mapper.ProjectTo<YourDTO>(_context.Blogs.Where(b => b.Id > 1).ToListAsync()
```

_mapper is injected into your constructor:

```
private readonly IMapper _mapper;

public YourContrroller(IMapper mapper){
    _mapper = mapper;
}
```